# how to make my text in textview with multi color?

Tags: java, android, textview

i'm building an app on android studio that have results for specific calculations and i need to make some notes within the result with red color, see the example:

take in your consideration (r1,r2,r3) are strings

```
result.setText ( "creat result" +
"\n salaz " + r1+
"\n jalf " +r2+
"\n mdar" +r3 

);
```

the result:

> salaz 20 mg
>
> jalf 10 mg
>
> mdar 5 mg

So i need jalf 10 mg with red line

need this line with red `"\n jalf " +r2+"`

Is there any way to make it red ?!!?

Comment: Not per se, but I believe you can set html that will render how you want it to.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work, but in theory it should.

```
Spannable r1Span = new SpannableString(r1);
Spannable r2Span = new SpannableString(r2);
Spannable r3Span = new SpannableString(r3);

r1Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, r1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
r2Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, r2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
r3Span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, r3.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

String result = TextUtils.concat("creat result" +
"\n salaz " + r1Span+
"\n jalf " +r2Span+
"\n mdar" +r3Span); 

result.setText (result);
```

Let me know how it went.

Comment: Woops, i had a typo in there. Edited it and it should work now.

Comment: i do it but the color doesn't change to red !! i appreciate that from you but if you tried it and got the result with the red color , tell me with the update

Answer (score 0):

Give a try and let me know if it works:

```
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#006400\">" + "Price: $" + _price + "   " + "</font>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "<font color=\"#3F23F5\">" + "Rooms:  " + _room+ "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +  "</font>"
                                     + "     " + "<font color=\"#DF7401\">" + "District:  " + _district + "</font>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
int colorRed = getResources().getColor(R.color.red); 
String text = getString(R.string.text);
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text); // here we set the color
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorBlue), 0, text.length(), 0);

yourTextView.setText(spannable);
```

Handle the length here till where you want to set the color